# Empty array fields cause json_encode's output type to change from JSONArray to JSONObject

Tags: php, arrays, json

This code's output type is JSONArray:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;++$i)
{
    $data[$i]['Name'] = 'myname'.$i;
}
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;
```

Result:

```
[{"Name":"myname0"},{"Name":"myname1"},{"Name":"myname2"},{"Name":"myname3"}]
```

But when I skip some of them, It's output type will be JSONObject!!!:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;++$i)
{
    $data[$i]['Name'] = 'myname'.$i;
    ++$i;
}

$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;
```

Result:

```
{"0":{"Name":"myname0"},"2":{"Name":"myname2"}}
```

Why?!

And as you can see, their field numbers will be as names for those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric
>   sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and
>   specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

The 2nd example in your question obviously refers to the situation above. That's why the result JSON become JS `object`.

Comment: @M D P You could upvote this answer as well if it's really helpful for you